# Как назначить TextWatcher на EditField при MVP

Tags: java, android, архитектура, mvp

Есть MainActivity, есть Presenter, есть отдельный класс Util который наследуется от TextWatcher. 
Задача в том, чтобы назначить этот TextWatcher на editField.

Сейчас MainActivity

```
 mainPresenterImpl = new MainPresenterImpl();
 mainPresenterImpl.translationInputFieldListener(translatedTextInput);
```

Presenter

```
@Override
public void translationInputFieldListener(EditText translatedTextInput) {
    Log.v("TAG", "In presenter");
    translatedTextInput.addTextChangedListener(textWatcherUtil = new TextWatcherUtil());
}
```

Util

```
public class TextWatcherUtil implements TextWatcher{

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
}
```

}

Задача, назначить в методе afterTextChanged. Там уже дальше будет выполнятся метод сохранения значения в SharedPreferences.

P.S. Если мой вопрос составлен не корректно, то если минусуете, пожалуйста отпишите в комментариях, что сделанно не верно, чтобы ошибок не повторялось. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textWatcher` это из категории дата биндинга в сторону `MVVM`. В случае паттерна `MVP` `TextWatcher'a` держите во вьюхе и в его колбеках вызываете презентер. и вся логика уже в презентере. т.е. будет вот так:

```
public class TextWatcherUtil implements TextWatcher{

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
     presenter.beforeTextChanged(...);
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
   presenter.onTextChanged(...);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
   presenter.afterTextChanged(...);
}
```

Т.е. в вашем конкретном случае, вы в коллбеке `afterTextChanged()` вызываете `presenter.onTextChanged()` и в этом методе презентер вызывает свои `Private` методы работы с префами

А если у вас идет работа с префами, что можно считать репозиторием, то можете прикрутить к `MVP` еще и `Interactor` если простым языком, это класс между презнтером и моделью, который преобразует данные (+логику работы с ними) из модели в презентер и обратно в необходимом виде

Comment: У меня он изначально и был во вьюхе((( Хотел вьюху почистить. А можно ли TextWatcher в другой класс вынести?

Comment: если попроще - TextWatcher по своей природе аналогичен Клик лиснерам. вы же их в отдельные классы или презентер не выносите. они лежат во вьюхе и дергают нужные методы презентера